# Memory issues when vectorizing Oja's rule in a loop

Tags: matlab, vector, neural-network, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I am running into memory issues while attempting to vectorize code that implements [Oja's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oja's_rule). How can I avoid the memory issues?

```
for iter = 1:options.niter
    for ii = 1:n %// n=400
        y = w'*X(:,ii); %'// y is a scalar, not a vector
        w = w + options.rate*(y*X(:,ii) - y^2*w);
    end;

    if (any(~isfinite(w)))
        warning(sprintf('Lost convergence at iterator %i; lower learning rate?', iter));
        break
    end
end;
```

Dimensions:

```
 w:             156300x1
 X:             156300x400
 options.rate:  scalar
 options.niter: scalar
 y:             scalar
```

Edit slightly more vectorized:

```
    y = w'*X;
    for ii = 1:n       
        % y is a scalar, not a vector
        w = w + options.rate*(y(ii)*X(:,ii) - y(ii)^2*w);
    end
```

Note: I don't care much about

```
if (any(~isfinite(w)))
    warning(sprintf('Lost convergence at iterator %i; lower learning rate?', iter));
    break
end
```

I would move it out of the `iter` loop if all is vectorized.

Comment: Is this the code which causes the memory errors? Looks memory efficient to me.

Comment: Maybe you could use one of the Matlab integer datatypes. Where do the memory problems occur? See Matlab Profiler with Memory Usage: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/profiling-matlab-memory-usage

Comment: @JaBe Not sure abt memory problem. Do you think the code in Edit 1 could be vectorized further?

Comment: If you are having memory issues with this then vectorising it won't help. As each iteration depends on the previous result a vectorised solution would require the storage of each values at each solution which would increase the amount of memory needed.